# css: How do I make a 'square' div by using css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a mobile only HTML page which splits the screen into tiles.

I have 5 tiles per row, so the tile width is determined as 20% of the screen. I would like the height to be the same - 20% of the screen **width**. Note that's hight = 20% of device width, not height. The page will scroll downward if there are more tiles.

Is there any way to do this with CSS? I'd rather not have to javascript unless I have to.

Comment: not possible without javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: A way to maintain aspect ratio when resizing a DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div)

Comment: The other posters question is close enough to be considered a duplicate. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe CSS can do it by itself.  Use Javascript, or better and easier, use LessCSS ( lesscss.org )

Comment: Less is compiled css... by javascript. No js in the runtimes. Fyi - and i dont think less can facilitate this.. SASS maybe but that uses runtime js

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg JavaScript is just one way to compile less. Have a look at [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) for .Net for instance. I believe there is a ported version for most web related languages these days.

Comment: That's too bad. It seems like it would be a fairly frequent use-case.